# What is the difference between Number.parseFloat() or parseFloat()?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `Number.parseFloat()` and `parseFloat()`? Is one better than the other?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat

Comment: "The Number.parseFloat() method parses a string argument and returns a floating point number. This method behaves identically to the global function parseFloat() and is part of ECMAScript 2015 (its purpose is modularization of globals)."

Comment: They are identical. ES6 just sweeped related globals under the same thing.

Comment: Better how? `parsefloat()` doesn't exist, so I guess that's worse?

Comment: The two behave *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Neither]

They are the exact same function. They don't only behave the same. They are the exact same function object.

To expand on that, `Number.parseFloat()` was created in ECMAScript 2015, as part of an effort to modularize globals [because global functions with no namespace makes me sad :(]

Comment: @DavidWalschots I guess it's because it's related to the question. The question is bad, no doubt about it - it shows no research effort whatsoever, so it deserves downvotes. This answer is fine, though. Probably redundant, considering it's re-stating what's in the docs but that's OK, I think. It's the question that shouldn't be here if there was any real attempt to look at the docs.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee at all that `Number.parseFloat === parseFloat` will remain true along time (but I doubt they will diverge, the most probable outcome is that `parseFloat` will disappear someday).

Comment: @VLAZ my 'research' brought me to this question and answer. It answered my question.. So as far as I am concerned, it's a great question, because it's the same question I had.

Comment: @VLAZ this had a score in google than the Docs.. so this came first, so I spotted it first, so no need to read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

## `parseFloat` vs. `Number.parseFloat`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

`parseFloat === Number.parseFloat // => true`

--

`parseFloat` is accessible via the Global scope as of ES2015

> **parseFloat**
>
> > From MDN:
> >     its purpose is modularization of globals

--

`Number.parseFloat` is available via a method on the `Number` object (also since ES2015).

In either case, the behavior for both function calls is identical. Both will type coerce the input into a Number if possible (**e.g.:** `parseFloat('67') // => 67`) or return `NaN` if the parsed input wasn't able to be coerced.

Comment: `Both will type coerce the input into a Number if possible` that is incorrect. As the name suggests, the function(s) will *parse* the input and extract a float. If you call `parseFloat("12.34abc")` the result would be `12.34` as the function will only stop parsing when it finds a character that cannot be used to build a number, thus extracting the numeric value from the beginning of the string. `NaN` will be the result if the input starts with a non-numeric character. `parseFloat is accessible via the Global scope as of ES2015` also incorrect - it's in the spec as global from version 1.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have said: they are exactly the same.

However(writing 2019), parseFloat has IE11 support, while Number.parseFloat does not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat

Comment: This is still the case - and also bootstrap 5.0 uses Number.parseFloat, which fails for IE 11.